# Lightning: aura:iteration - how to refer indexVar variable inside loop to access elements in List?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, loop, aura

What is the way to refer index variable inside looping [aura:iteration](https://cs41.lightning.force.com/auradocs#reference?descriptor=aura:iteration&defType=component)?

The code below results in error:

> Failed to save undefined: expecting a positive integer, found 'indx'
>   at column 10 of expression: v.labels[indx]: Source

```
    <aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.items}" indexVar="indx">
        <li>
            <label class="card-detail-label">{!v.labels[indx]}</label>
            <span class="card-detail-value">{!item}</span>  
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 18):

It does not look like a variable defined as indexVar was meant to be used as part of another expression.

e.g. this works

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="item" indexVar="index">
{!index} : {!item.FirstName}<br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

I think in your example "item" should be changed from final value to an object which has properties .label and .value, something like this:

```
<aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.items}">
        <li>
            <label class="card-detail-label">{!item.label}</label>
            <span class="card-detail-value">{!item.value}</span>  
        </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add counter as integer as in `indexVar` gives string in return, which we cannot use to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can only address the "[]" notation using an integer. It throws an error because it is not possible to access an object in an array using a variable

[see this related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198034/using-an-auraiteration-index-as-an-array-accessor)

One alternative is to create a wrapper component that has all its properties already set as attributes and then iterate on it. The framework has a poor dynamic logic implementation.

see @gaiser answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I found to do it  {#(index+1)}
Example used in a table

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Contacts}" var="contact" indexVar="index">
   <tr scope="row">
      <td> {#(index+1)}</td>   
      <td> {!contact.Name}</td>
   </tr>    
</aura:iteration>
```