# Read more than one attribute from select list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a component like that:

```
                    <lightning:select aura:id="selectedContact" onchange="{!c.onChangeFunction}">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.relatedContactList}" var="contact">
                            <option value="{!contact.LastName}" selectedLastName="{!contact.LastName}" selectedEmail="{!contact.Email}">{!contact.FirstName}&nbsp;{!contact.LastName} : {!contact.Email}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
```

And a client side controller that is triggered on a button with the following code:

```
console.log(cmp.find("selectedContact").get("v.selectedEmail"));
console.log(cmp.find("subjectLine").get("v.value"));   
console.log(cmp.find("rejectText").get("v.value"));
```

I can read the subjectLine and rejectText successfully, but not selectedEmail. It seems I can only access .value, not .anythingelse

How do I get the email in this example to my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Option tag, there are no attributes like selectedLastName , selectedEmail, thus you won't be able to bind it. Only **Value** attribute of option is what you can bind.

You have to change your strategy.  I can think up of using indexVar of aura:iteration. The idea is to store the selected index and use it in JS controller to get the contacts value.

```
<aura:attribute type="Integer" name="selectedContactIndex" default="0"/>
<lightning:select aura:id="selectedContact" onchange="{!c.onChangeFunction}"  value="{!v.selectedContactIndex}">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.relatedContactList}" var="contact" indexVar="index" >
                            <option value="{!index}" >{!contact.FirstName}&nbsp;{!contact.LastName} : {!contact.Email}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

And in JS.

```
var contactList =component.get("v.relatedContactList");
var selectedIndex = component.get("v.selectedContactIndex");
var selectedContact = contactList[selectedIndex];
console.log(selectedContact.Email);
console.log(selectedContact.FirstName);
console.log(selectedContact.LastName});
```

Src: [Lightning: aura:iteration - how to refer indexVar variable inside loop to access elements in List?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70861/lightning-auraiteration-how-to-refer-indexvar-variable-inside-loop-to-access?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm

Comment: Hey Pranay, thanks for your reply! That was news for me, I thought I could just read the attribute value.  The code above throws "The attribute "indexVar" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://lightning:select: Source" - do you know why this so by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: mybad.. indexVar is part of aura:iteration and not lightning select updated the code.